# (javascript) logical && and || operators in a same if statemtent

Tags: javascript

I want to execute this statement only if all these 3 following conditions are true:

1. flavor is "vanilla" or "chocolate"
2. vessel is "cone" or "bowl"
3. toppings is "sprinkles" or "peanuts"

**my code**

```
if ((flavor == "vanilla" || "chocolate") && (vessel == "cone" ||  "bowl") && (toppings == "sprinkles" || "peanuts")){

      console.log("I'd like two scoops of "+ flavor +" ice cream in a "+ vessel +" with "+toppings);

} else {

    console.log("I don't wanna eat ice cream");
}
```

when i run this program it always execute the if statement no matter what flavor, vessel i put in the values. why?

Comment: `flavor == "vanilla" || "chocolate"` is basically `flavor == "vanilla" || true` because non-empty strings are evaluated to true. If you want to compare variable against multiple values you just have to do `flavor == "vanilla" || flavor == "chocolate"`

Comment: Because JavaScript is not English. `flavor == "vanilla" || "chocolate"` means "the value of `flavor` is `"vanilla"`, or `"chocolate"` is a truthy value" - the latter of which is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flavor == "vanilla" || "chocolate"
```

must be

```
flavor == "vanilla" || flavor == "chocolate"
```

This will work just fine.

```
if ((flavor == "vanilla" || flavor == "chocolate")
    && (vessel == "cone" || vessel == "bowl")
    && (toppings == "sprinkles" || toppings == "peanuts")) {
        console.log("I'd like two scoops of " + flavor + " ice cream in a " + vessel + " with " + toppings);
} else {
    console.log("I don't wanna eat ice cream");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
if ((flavor == "vanilla" || flavor == "chocolate") && (vessel == "cone" || vessel ==  "bowl") && (toppings == "sprinkles" || toppings == "peanuts"))
```

by doing (xpto = 'something' || 'something) the last statment is always true

Answer (score 0):

Assume a variable `a`

```
var a = 2;
a == 3 || "yes" //print `yes`
```

Because     `a == 3 || "yes"`  is executed as     `(a == 3) || "yes"` which will return `"yes"` **which is a truthy value**.

In your case,   `flavor == "vanilla" || "chocolate"` is executed as `(flavor == "vanilla") || "chocolate"` which results in `"chocolate"` which is again a truthy value. **Hence the if-statement always evaluates to `true`**.

You need to **compare `flavor` against both values separately**, i.e.

```
flavor == "vanilla" || flavor == "chocolate"
```

Answer (score 0):

When performing such a command:

```
(flavor == "vanilla" || "chocolate")
```

it will always return "chocolate" (true) if flavor is not equal to "vanilla".

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem

```
flavor == "vanilla" || "chocolate"
```

I know it sounds like your saying if flavor equals vanilla or chocolate but this is incorrect the proper way to write this would look like

```
if ((flavor == "vanilla" || flavor == "chocolate") && (vessel == "cone" ||  vessel == "bowl") && 
(toppings == "sprinkles" || toppings == "peanuts")){

  console.log("I'd like two scoops of "+ flavor +" ice cream in a "+ vessel 
  +" with "+toppings);

 } else {

console.log("I don't wanna eat ice cream");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
<script>
flavor = "vanilla"
vessel = "cone"
toppings = "sprinkles"
if ((flavor == "vanilla" || flavor == "chocolate") && 
(vessel == "cone" || vessel == "bowl") && 
(toppings == "sprinkles" || toppings == "peanuts")){alert("success!")}
</script>
```